# C++ (CLR) mouse click to hidden window

Tags: c++

In a windows C++ CLR project I am trying to build a function that can send a mouse click to absolute x, y coords in a out of focus / minimized / hidden window.

The function is controlled by pressing a button on the app GUI.

Doing some research on google and on stackoverflow I put together the code below:

```
void click(int x, int y) {
    POINT pt;
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, L"winWithThisClass", NULL);
    if (hWnd)
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
        Sleep(130);
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
    }
}
```

The above code does send a click to the minimized window, but not at specified coords.

The click is sent to the minimized window at the coords of the mouse pressing button on the GUI.

So whereever the GUI is located on the desktop, when I press the button that runs the function, the click is sent to the minimized window at the GUI's button coords.

Any ideeas on how I can make this code work as intended?

Thanks

Comment: It is not a sensible operation, the window would not expect a click.  If it could work at all then the x/y parameters matter, they would be have to be highly negative (near -32000). 
 Use GetClientRect() to see that.

Comment: If I set focus to the window (SetForegroundWindow) sleep a few seconds then perform the code above, it still does not work and the click is sent to the GUI's button coordinates. So i figure there is a problem with the code... as it should have sent the click correctly on the focused window...

Comment: P.S: performing GetWindowRect on the minimized window gets me valid, positive coords, same as if bring the window to foreground before runinng the code